# Do you lose all your progress with challenges in black ops 3 when you prestige

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

Same as question above... when you reach level 55 and prestige, do you lose the progress of all the challenges you've completed?

I already know that you keep your weapons camo and attachments and your specialists progress.  Just need to know about the regular challenges.

And i'm assuming that you keep the progress of the challenges under the prestige tab but if someone can confirm that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You retain your progress for the Challenges like Boot Camp or Killer, and you also get the opportunity for the Prestige Challenges that include perks, wildcards, specialist weapons, etc.